# Add values to a Multiple Metadata column via SQL

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, migration, term-store, term

I am trying to add multiple values to a multiple metadata column via SQL using a third party migration tool (Layer 2), but it only works when I add one value as explained below.

I have written some testing code like this in SQL

```
Select …
,'Qualifications;BA'
From
```

(Where Qualifications is the termset and BA and BSc are the terms)

[image]

And it works with just the one value with the SQL shown above.

[image]

However, I want this

[image]

To try to do this, I have amended the SQL like so

```
,'Qualifications;BA;BSC'
,'Qualifications;BA; Qualifications;Bsc '
,'Qualifications;[BA];[BSC]'
```

But sharepoint does not attempt the format and wont add any values

The error I get back from the software is

[image]

Does anyone know what the SQL should be to make this work, if possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a pipe e.g. '|' to the list

```
'Qualifications;BSc|BA'
```